# TypeError: req.send is not a function NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I get the error TypeError: req.send is not a function

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const courses = [
  { id: 1, name: "courses2" },
  { id: 2, name: "courses2" },
  { id: 3, name: "courses2" }
];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello Word");
});

app.get("/api/courses", (req, res) => {
  req.send(courses);
});
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: req.send is not a function
    at app.get (/home/sambulo/Desktop/express-server/index.js:15:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sambulo/Desktop/express-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/sambulo/Desktop/express-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/sambulo/Desktop/express-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sambulo/Desktop/express-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/sambulo/Desktop/express-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/sambulo/Desktop/express-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/sambulo/Desktop/express-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/home/sambulo/Desktop/express-server/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sambulo/Desktop/express-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be res.send() than req.send()?

Comment: Did you mean to do res.send? unless you have a method attached to your request than yes, req.send is not a function

Answer (score 1):

**It should be res.send() not req.send()**

You're trying to access a method on request object which which doesen't have send method.

```
app.get("/api/courses", (req, res) => {
  res.send(courses);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/api/courses", (req, res) => {
  req.send(courses);
});
```

Please use res.send instead of req.send